# Appium MobileElement.tap(); not working on iosSimulator 8.2 for mobile web

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium, mobile-website

I'm using Java to automate tests for mobile web on ios safari

Everything seems to be set up correctly but appium is crashing with the error:

```
uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
```

the touch command comes through in the logs like so:

```
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/1a925d31-d3cd-4231-9698-f7ff4db739fd/touch/perform {"actions":[{"action":"press","options":{"element":"5001"}},{"action":"wait","options":{"ms":1}},{"action":"release","options":{}}]}
info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.getElement('5001').rect()"
info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.getElement('5001').rect()
```

my code looks like this:

```
public void tap(MobileElement element) {
        appiumDriver.context(getContext("NATIVE"));
        element.tap(1,1);
        appiumDriver.context(getContext("WEBVIEW"));
}

protected String getContext(String partial) {
    String result = null;
        Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String contextName : contextNames) {
            if(contextName.contains(partial)){
                result = contextName;
            }
        }
    if (result == null){
        throw new NoSuchContextException("Could not find requested context");
    }
    return result;
}
```

and I'm feeding it a mobileElement.

I can get the element location by treating it like a `WebElement` and doing `getlocation()` and then I can use a `TouchAction`, which works in terms of what appium is doing, but the location is super off so I'm trying to use the `mobileElement` `tap()` action here instead.

Does anyone know a workaround or see what I might be doing wrong? My site has a lot of elements that require a `tap()`.

This also occurs when I define a `WebElement`, then move into Native context and use `iosDriver.tap(1, webelement, 1);` with the same crash on the appium side.

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
   AppiumDriver appiumDriver = new AppiumDriver();
    String originalContext = appiumDriver.getContext();
    Point coordinate = element.getLocation();
    Dimension loc = element.getSize();
    int centerX = loc.getWidth() / 2 + coordinate.getX();
    int centerY = loc.getHeight() / 2 + coordinate.getY();
    appiumDriver.context("NATIVE_APP");
    appiumDriver.tap(1, centerX, centerY, 2);
    appiumDriver.context(originalContext);
```

The Issues is that, in Native context Appium does not have any visibility to webelements on the webPage, You need to get the coordinated and then click using Tap method with coordinates